# python - Generate a random binary tree with n vertices

Tags: python, random, binary-tree

I am debugging an algorithms task, and for the purpose of testing I want to generate a binary tree with n vertices rooted at 0, in other words, generate a sequence of pairs so that if the i-th pair in the sequence is (a,b), then the left child of i-th node is a, and the right child is b, except when a (or b) = -1, then i-th node has no left (or right) child. (e. g. a sequence: (1, 2), (-1, -1), (-1, -1) is a tree with the root (0), and two children (1 and 2))
I wrote the following python recursive function, where listAdd is the desired pair list, listDel is all vertices not yet generated, and n is the node currently being looked at:

```
 
def generateTree(listAdd, listDel, n):
    if not listDel:
        return
    ifLeft = bool(randint(0,1))
    ifRight = bool(randint(0,1))
    if ifLeft:
        chosen = choice(listDel)
        listDel.remove(chosen)
        listAdd[n] = (chosen, listAdd[n][1])
        generateTree(listAdd, listDel, chosen)
    else:
        listAdd[n] = (-1, listAdd[n][1])
    if not listDel:
        return
    if ifRight:
        chosen = choice(listDel)
        listDel.remove(chosen)
        listAdd[n] = (listAdd[n][0], chosen)
        generateTree(listAdd, listDel, chosen)
    else:
        listAdd[n] = (listAdd[n][0], -1)
```

However, upon writing it, I noticed that this does not work correctly, as it is possible for the function to stop after just one vertex, if ifLeft and ifRight both come out as false.

So my question is, what is a good way to generate such a tree? I don't need it to be in python, as it's only for generating an input file, all I need is a good algorithm, or another method of representing the tree so that it's easier to generate and can be converted into the desired format.

Comment: I would keep a list of leaf nodes. randomly select one leaf node, remove it from list and add its two children. repeat n times.

Comment: @kazemakase This way you will always generate a balanced tree, while I'm looking for something that generates any tree, even degenerate ones like a path.

Comment: Assuming I understood correctly, it will come out balanced, or at least close to it, as when you select a node, if there are two or more leaf nodes, two of them will get connected to that node, so there is no chance that it will have one or 0 children, unless you generate a number of children randomly, but then you lose the guarantee of connectedness, which I need.

Comment: Hmm.. well, the tree would be constricted to an odd number of nodes (each node could have either 0 or 2 children) but imbalance is possible.

Comment: Can you show an example input to the function, and what the output might look like?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that all restrictions can be removed by keeping a list of free edges rather than nodes. See answer :)

Comment: Just in case if anyone wants to generate random tree (for their usage in code not testing an algorithm) use [networkx package](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.trees.random_tree.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple iterative approach:

```
import random

# start with root node and no children
tree = [[-1, -1]]
free_edges = [(0, 0), (0, 1)]

n = 4  # how many nodes do you want?

while len(tree) < n:
    e = random.choice(free_edges)  # select a free edge
    node, child = e
    assert tree[node][child] == -1  # make sure we made no mistake

    k = len(tree)  # index of new node
    tree.append([-1, -1])  # add new node

    tree[node][child] = k  # set new node as child of an old node
    free_edges.extend([(k, 0), (k, 1)])  # new node has two free edges

    free_edges.remove(e)  # edge is no longer free

print(tree)
# [[1, 2], [-1, 3], [-1, -1], [-1, -1]]
```

Randomly insert new nodes into the tree until the total number of nodes is reached.

[image]
The free edges are indicated in red. At each step, one free edge is chosen at random. A node is placed at that edge and this node adds two new free edges to the tree.

This procedure does not generate a specific order of nodes. Either the left child or the right child may be inserted into the tree first. I.e. you may get a sequence like `[(2, 1), (-1, -1), (-1, -1)]`. If this is a problem re-ordering of the nodes may be necessary.

---

I think this method will on average tend to produce more balanced trees than imbalanced trees because older edges are be considered more often. You may choose not to insert a new node and only remove the free edge with a certain probability. This should shift the tendency towards deeper trees. Just make sure not to remove all edges before being finished :)

Comment: While it isn't capable of generating all labeled binary trees, as I originally thought I would need the algorithm to, it can generate any tree up to an isomorphism, which is, as I now realize, all I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I hat to look up isomorphism, which betrays my lack of formal education on the topic :) Out of curiosity, what kind of tree can't it create?

Comment: Every path from the root to any leaf is guaranteed to have strictly ascending labels, so any tree that doesn't satisfy that can't be generated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must not get a double zero when you're on the right end of your tree while still having some free elements, is that correct?

So I think you need to determine when this happens, AND force a recheck. There are 2 approaches that I can think of.

- Make a function that checks where you are if you give it the root.
- Create an array and populate it with `0`,`1` or `"L"`,`"R"`. If you have

  - `ifLeft == ifRight == 0`
  - `len(listDel) > 0` And
  - Checking the array, either:

    - `If "L" not in check_array`
    - `if len(check_array) == sum(check_array)`

Re-load the whole thing.

And by the way, you have to add the check to your array at the beginning of your function and remove it at the end. So its length will be like this:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0

```
check_array = []

def generateTree(listAdd, listDel, n):
    if not listDel:
        return
    ifLeft = bool(randint(0,1))
    ifRight = bool(randint(0,1))

    if (ifLeft + ifRight == 0) and (
        "L" not in checked_array) and (
        len(listDel) > 0):
        // Force a 1, or use randint (you need a while-loop for it)
        ifLeft = 1

    if ifLeft:
        check_array.push("L")
        chosen = choice(listDel)
        listDel.remove(chosen)
        listAdd[n] = (chosen, listAdd[n][1])
        generateTree(listAdd, listDel, chosen)
        check_array = check_array[:-1]
    else:
        listAdd[n] = (-1, listAdd[n][1])
    if not listDel:
        return
    if ifRight:
        check_array.push("R")
        chosen = choice(listDel)
        listDel.remove(chosen)
        listAdd[n] = (listAdd[n][0], chosen)
        generateTree(listAdd, listDel, chosen)
        check_array = check_array[:-1]
    else:
        listAdd[n] = (listAdd[n][0], -1)
```